# scnBox with scnTube through the middle

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have been digging around trying to find a way to show a game board of sorts.

It is basically a square board with a round hole in the middle, I am able to render the scnBox and the scnTube, but I would like the area where the scnTube sits in the box for the box to be transparent and see through the game board, but can't seem to find anywhere that has an example.  Any help would be much appreciated. I am hoping that I am just missing something very simple, but this is my first time using scene kit.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you want a box with a hole in the middle, not a box and a tube.

Comment: That is correct, I just thought using the tube would be the easiest way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Unreal Engine 4, (UDK and prior) Epic's modelling space was subtraction - a filled block was your game world and its extents. From inside this block you took chunks out to create space for players to run around in, and shoot each other. All's fair in love and war.

I'm telling you this because it's a good example of how contrived 3D modelling is compared to real world scenarios, and should (hopefully) put you at sufficient unease to digest what follows.

This approach of carving out of a finite block is still in Unreal Engine 4 and popular with older users, but it now defaults to an open, infinite world into which things are added. Most new users gravitate towards building into an infinite space of nothingness rather than carving space out of a solid, finite block.

Everything about 3D modelling is virtual, and virtually impossible to relate to the real world. Instead of thinking in terms of how things could be done if objects were real and literal, you need to think in terms of the limitations (and there are many) of geometry definitions as used in most 3D modelling and game engines.

The programming equivalent of this mental gymnastics is going from the concept of classes and objects to their realities within languages and frameworks. On the one hand the ideas and their ideals are wonderful, and on the other the realities are a bleak reminder that programming languages haven't really progressed very far, at all.

3D modelling is exactly like this. It's not much further along than it was decades ago, and is still using archaic ways to solve many of its original problems.

Cutting a nice, clean, efficient round hole in a cube is one such original problem.

A very simple shape is being intersected and cut by a shape with the potential for infinite complexity. What should happen? Should the simple become complex or the complex become simple? How to make the most graceful transition between the two?

That's the problem you're facing: a cube is a simple geometric shape, easily defined by minimal line segments. A cylinder introduces infinite possibilities for line segmentation around its circumference.

So somewhere along the lines of development, the architects of 3D modelling had to come up with a way to make these contrasting line complexities play well together for lightweight presentation on limited hardware. Their solution, in most cases, is a hybrid and a disaster of user operability, but masterful in its geometric efficiency: Polygon modelling, UVW unwrapping and subdivision!

All of which means that if you want to achieve this in the best way possible, with today's tools, for the purposes of Scene Kit, I suggest polygon modelling this board in Maya for 4 reasons.

1. It's got a 30 day free trial.
2. It works on a Mac
3. It's polygon modelling tools are second only to 3ds Max
4. It's easier to learn (for a complete newcomer) than MODO, and miles easier to learn than Blender.

MODO is interesting if you're already skilled in Polygon modelling, but it's so utterly discombobulating if you don't have that prior experience that I'd recommend using just about anything else first. Except Blender. Blender is free, but don't be tempted. It will cost you more in learning time than buying a copy of every other professional 3D app.

In MODO's favour, and the reason I mention it, it does export nicely for Scene Kit. I know that for a fact, but am not yet sure how well Maya exports for Scene Kit.

Which is the next problem you're going to come up against. All COLLADA files are not born equal.

New Maya does have Unity and Unreal export presets, so I presume it's possible to calibrate its COLLADA exports to match the demands of Scene Kit perfectly, just haven't yet needed to do it. This will (very likely) involve trial and error to get the settings right. It would be nice if Apple would tell us exactly how to configure export from all major 3D apps for Scene Kit, but instead they're giving us the half baked Model I/O, so we can double the effort of importing artwork.

All context aside (which has largely been to demonstrate that 3D is no simpler nor more refined than using an IDE and frameworks like Xcode and Cocoa), here's the meat and potatoes:

A video on one aspect of what's best to make holes, and starts out as you are, with a cube and a cylinder:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaEv5rio8bk

But it does presume a certain amount of Maya familiarity, some of which you can gain from this rather slow and ponderous examination of two other ways to make holes in cubes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvMfoH5Ikrc

Yes, if you're counting, that's 3 ways to make holes. Actually four, because the first video starts with the boolean operation you might have been expecting to be how this could/should be done. In some parallel future we'll have well working boolean geometry operations. We're not there, yet.

Hopefully that same parallel future will offer us a programming language, frameworks and terminology that's not confusing and maintains metaphors long enough to make teaching easy and usage elegant and simple.

Comment: Holy crap, I had no idea that trying to do something that I perceived should be simple was so complex.  Thank you very much for the extremely detailed explanation and resource links.

Comment: Like programming, it should have become simple. However there's little commercial incentive to making it so, and an entire industry dependent on it being almost impenetrable for all but the most resolutely determined. A parallel is the 50+ lines of code and understanding of OOP, iOS and UIKit's layerings used to create a simple "Hello World" app.

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating a bezier path as close to the shape I wanted as I could get then made an SCNShape() out of it with the extrusionDepth that I wanted. Then I created a small SCNBox to hide the gap left from using the bezier path. It may not be elegant, but it worked. I wasn't able to use the solutions above because the diameter is not fixed.

Comment: Here's another hacky way to do the varying sizes you need: Animate the size of the hole and/or extrusion you need, from min to max, in a 3D app, then use the various positions in time to get the size you need and depth you need whenever you need it. Obviously this require using some kind of determinable mapping of time to size/depth to work with any kind of accuracy. But it should work. Unfortunately the geometry in SceneKit is immutable, which is kind of weird/odd/unfortunate... but the other way could be a geometry shader that changes the diameter/depth, but will require good geometry to do.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about that long answer but this can be achieved with Boolean Subtraction. You create a cube and a cylinder. You subtract the cylinder from the cube. In 3ds Max this is under compound objects-modifiers-boolean subtraction. I guess Maya has a similair function somwhere in the menus.